# type mismatch; found : Seq[play.api.libs.json.JsObject] required: Seq[play.api.libs.json.Json.JsValueWrapper]

Tags: playframework-2.5

I am working on converting Sequence of Custom Object into JSON format using Play Framework 2.5.6.

Below is my code.

```
import play.api.libs.json.Json
import play.api.libs.json.JsObject


case class Item (id:Long,name:String,price:Double) 
object SerializingListIntoJSON {

  def details(itemList: Seq[Item]) = {
    **Json.arr(itemList.map(item => Json.obj("id" -> item.id,"name" -> item.name,"price" -> item.price)): _*)**
  }

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val itemList = Seq(Item(1, "Programming Scala", 49.99), Item(2, "Scala in Action", 44.99))

    println(details(itemList))
  }
}
```

The code is giving me the compilation error in the bold line saying "type mismatch;  found   : Seq[play.api.libs.json.JsObject]  required: Seq[play.api.libs.json.Json.JsValueWrapper]".

I am not sure what is wrong with my code. Any help on this is deeply appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The following

```
def details(itemList: Seq[Item]) = {
  JsArray(itemList.map(item =>
    Json.obj("id" -> item.id, "name" -> item.name, "price" -> item.price)))
}
```

produces a result of:

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Programming Scala",
    "price": 49.99
  },
  ...
]
```

if that is what you are after? If you haven't seen [the Play Scala JSON documentation](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/ScalaJson) yet, then you might find discussion of Writes and Reads helpful, amongst other details and examples there.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a helper function that converts a Scala sequence of `JsValue` instances to a `JsArray`:

```
def toJsArray(seq: Seq[JsValue]): JsArray = {
    seq.foldLeft(JsArray.empty)((a, b) => a ++ Json.arr(b)).as[JsArray]
}
```

It wraps each `JsValue` in its own `JsArray` and then unions them together.